# several iPads talking to a single main iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to develop an app where several ipads communicate to a single main iPad.  Would this be done using Bonjour or Game Kit? I looked at Bluetooth but that seems like a 1 to 1 communication. I have never messed with either of these API's

Comment: This may not help, but have you considered using websockets? http://pusher.com/ allows you to easily use an entire realtime platform without the complications. It has many language wrappers to.

Comment: Third-party service (maybe you own) would be better solution.

Comment: needs to be completely independent of any network, cannot be constrained by internet access - this looks cool though

Comment: Have you considered working with a central server?  Like how `bump` implements communications?

Comment: I was hoping that one of the iPad's could the central server that the other ipad's talk to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Bonjour to do this -- but remember that Bonjour is only a framework to *advertise services* and doesn't do any of the actual connection itself.

For Bonjour, you need to create an NSNetServicesBrowser to scan the network (which can use Bluetooth -- or WiFi) and publish an NTNetService with the port for the other iPads to connect to (this could be the "master" iPad itself).

Then you would need to run a server on the "master" iPad (that is advertising the service) and then have some sockets code to handle all of that. (For which I recommend AsyncSocket (http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/).

Let me know if this is something you would be interested in doing, and I would be able to provide some code snippets as a starting point...

Comment: thanks for this, can the main iPad talk to multiple ipad's at the same time using Bluetooth?  Any code snippets would be greatly appreciated.  Reading this now: http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxviii-bonjour-and-how-do-you-do

Comment: To be honest, there's not much more I can add to the excellent code samples provided on the site you posted.

Just remember that Bonjour is only for advertising (and resolving) services and not for doing any actual connection. You will need other code for that.

In terms of Bluetooth, sorry but I have no real experience of Bluetooth on iPad, as all of my work has been done with WiFi. But remember that Bonjour will by default publish over both WiFi and Bluetooth.

Comment: GameKit over Bluetooth is restricted to one to one; it also has relatively poor performance, so I would suggest Bonjour/WiFi as the way to go, unless you want to really take the innards of Bluetooth apart (and create multiple one-to-one connections and switch between them).

Answer (score 0):

Like Glycerin said earlier, take a look at WebSockets. You can choose to have one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many connections, and is insanely fast.

[Here's a tutorial on Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)

Comment: you can do WebSockets over WiFi with no internet connection?  Maybe I didn't mention this needs to be an iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are the way to go. I would suggest learning about the basics of sockets, there are implementation in most programming languages. This helped me a lot: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ After getting a understanding of what sockets are and what they do u could use the CocoaAsyncSocket-Framework http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ on iOS. It adds an additional level of abstraction to sockets that helps especially with non-blocking network communication. There is some sample code available.